# Split colon separated strings into array

Tags: arrays, bash, split

I want to split colon separated strings into an array. Each loop I have string like `ONE:TWO:THREE` now how can I split it into an array so I could access it like `string[1] //ONE, string[2] //TWO, string[3] //THREE`?

This is the loop I use with the array content:

```
WORDS=(ONE:TWO:THREE FIVE:FOUR:THREE)
for i in ${WORDS[@]} ; do
   [..]
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
IFS=':' read -a arr <<< "$i"
```

After this you'll see that:

```
echo ${#arr}   # <-- 3
```

So your code would look something like:

```
for word in "${WORDS[@]}"; do
  IFS=':' read -a arr <<< "$word"

  for part in "${arr[@]}"; do
    # do something with the word  
  done
done
```

Comment: NOOOOOO! You forgot to quote your array!!!! ``for word in "${WORDS[@]}"`` and ``for part in "${arr[@]}"``